# Restore my default username?

Tags: feature-request, edits, profile-page, display-names

My username is refhat and is it possible that I could restore my default username that's when I joined stackoverflow something like **user765643**

Comment: Just [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/724764) it yourself?

Comment: You could also change your own username--there's no constraint on having duplicates if you mistakenly copy a user### that's already there.

Comment: @Chichiray: bit idk what what that username?

Comment: Why do you need to have a username you don't know?

Comment: @simchona: I am asking about the username which I was assigned when I joined SE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to your [user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/724764/refhat). Look closely at the URL in the browser address bar.

> https://stackoverflow.com/users/724764/refhat

Those digits `724764` represent your user ID. So your default user name was "user724764". You can just edit yourself in the "Display Name" field of the [edit user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/724764) page.